# How to exclude parts of a line in regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Out of the line `Your name is: "Foo Bar"` I want to select `Foo Bar` in regex only.

I have tried non-capturing groups without success : `(?:^Your name is: ").*(?:")$`

`"(.*?)"` Works but I don't want the double quotes to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lookbehind` and `lookahead`:

`(?<=^Your name is: ").+(?="$)`

`(?<=` looks behind for `Your name is: "` and
`(?=` looks ahead for `"`.

The result will be whatever is between that.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/k8LltM/1)

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged *pcre*, you don't have to use a lookbehind assertion but you can match the text and then use `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

```
^Your name is: "\K.+(?="$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAmwoJ/1).

Or without lookarounds at all and a capture group:

```
^Your name is: "(.+)"$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/miPJb9/1).